# How to poll with a Future in Scala?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future, polling

I want to poll an API endpoint until it reaches some condition. I expect it to reach this condition in couple of seconds to a minute. I have a method to call the endpoint that returns a `Future`. Is there some way I can chain `Future`s together to poll this endpoint every `n` milliseconds and give up after `t` tries?

Assume I have a function with the following signature:

```
def isComplete(): Future[Boolean] = ???
```

The simplest way to do this in my opinion would be to make everything blocking:

```
def untilComplete(): Unit = {
  for { _ <- 0 to 10 } {
    val status = Await.result(isComplete(), 1.seconds)
    if (status) return Unit
    Thread.sleep(100)
  }
  throw new Error("Max attempts")
}
```

But this may occupy all the threads and it is not asynchronous. I also considered doing it recursively:

```
def untilComplete(
    f: Future[Boolean] = Future.successful(false),
    attempts: Int = 10
  ): Future[Unit] = f flatMap { status =>
    if (status) Future.successful(Unit)
    else if (attempts == 0) throw new Error("Max attempts")
    else {
      Thread.sleep(100)
      untilComplete(isComplete(), attempts - 1)
    }
}
```

However, I am concerned about maxing out the call stack since this is not tail recursive.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Edit: I am using akka

Comment: For what you need, you might want to consider using Akka's [scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scheduler.html?language=scala).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/index.html). For example, to call `isComplete` every 500 milliseconds until the result of the `Future` is true, up to a maximum of five times:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{ Sink, Source }
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def isComplete(): Future[Boolean] = ???

implicit val system = ActorSystem("MyExample")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

val stream: Future[Option[Boolean]] =
  Source(1 to 5)
    .throttle(1, 500 millis)
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(_ => isComplete())
    .takeWhile(_ == false, true)
    .runWith(Sink.lastOption)

stream onComplete { result =>
  println(s"Stream completed with result: $result")
  system.terminate()
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I actually need some data from `isComplete` that isn't represented in my simplified implementation and I got this data using `inclusive = true` on the `takeWhile` and `Sink.lastOption`. Leaving this hear so others can do this as well.

Comment: This doesn't ensure we don't try further if we get a successful result before making all the 5 tries, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

It is actually not recursive *at all*, so the stack will be fine.

One improvement to your approach I can think of is to use some sort of scheduler instead of `Thread.sleep` so that you don't hold up the thread.

This example uses standard java's `TimerTask`, but if you are using some kind of a framework, like akka, play or whatever, it probably has its own scheduler, that would be a better alternative.

```
object Scheduler {
   val timer = new Timer(true)
   def after[T](d: Duration)(f :=> Future[T]): Future[T] = {
     val promise = Promise[T]()
     timer.schedule(TimerTask { def run() = promise.completeWith(f) }, d.toMillis)
     promise.future
   }
}


def untilComplete(attempts: Int = 10) = isComplete().flatMap { 
   case true => Future.successful(())
   case false if attempts > 1 => Scheduler.after(100 millis)(untilComplete(attempts-1))
   case _ => throw new Exception("Attempts exhausted.") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using akka. Would the `after` from [akka.pattern](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.1/#akka.pattern.package) in place of your `Scheduler.after` work in this example?

Comment: Sure, that's perfect

Comment: Also how is this not recursive? `untilComplete` calls itself

Comment: (`untilComplete` asks the `Scheduler` to call itself in a different `Thread`, with a different call stack.)

Comment: @user1943992 what Steve said :) It does not really call itself, it creates an anonymous function calling itself, that it then passes as an argument to `Scheduler`, that will at some point call it, after this call has completed. But more importantly, all of _that_ happens inside an anonymous function passed to `.flatMap`, that itself will be invoked after the first call completes. That's the reason your original snippet isn't recursive either, even though it does not use the `Scheduler`

Answer (score 4):

I've given myself a library to do this. I have

```
trait Poller extends AutoCloseable {
  def addTask[T]( task : Poller.Task[T] ) : Future[T]
  def close() : Unit
}
```

where a `Poller.Task` looks like

```
class Task[T]( val label : String, val period : Duration, val pollFor : () => Option[T], val timeout : Duration = Duration.Inf )
```

The `Poller` polls every `period` until the `pollFor` method succeeds (yields a `Some[T]`) or the `timeout` is exceeded.

As a convenience, when I begin polling, I wrap this into a `Poller.Task.withDeadline`:

```
final case class withDeadline[T] ( task : Task[T], deadline : Long ) {
  def timedOut = deadline >= 0 && System.currentTimeMillis > deadline
}
```

which converts the (immutable, reusable) `timeout` Duration of the task into a per-poll-attempt deadline for timing out.

To do the polling efficiently, I use Java's `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
def addTask[T]( task : Poller.Task[T] ) : Future[T] = {
  val promise = Promise[T]()
  scheduleTask( Poller.Task.withDeadline( task ), promise )
  promise.future
}

private def scheduleTask[T]( twd : Poller.Task.withDeadline[T], promise : Promise[T] ) : Unit = {
  if ( isClosed ) { 
    promise.failure( new Poller.ClosedException( this ) )
  } else {
    val task     = twd.task
    val deadline = twd.deadline

    val runnable = new Runnable {

      def run() : Unit = {
        try {
          if ( ! twd.timedOut ) {
            task.pollFor() match {
              case Some( value ) => promise.success( value )
              case None          => Abstract.this.scheduleTask( twd, promise )
            }
          } else {
            promise.failure( new Poller.TimeoutException( task.label, deadline ) )
          }
        }
        catch {
          case NonFatal( unexpected ) => promise.failure( unexpected )
        }
      }
    }

    val millis = task.period.toMillis
    ses.schedule( runnable, millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
  }
}
```

It seems to work well, without requiring sleeping or blocking of individual `Threads`.

(Looking at the library, there's lots that could be done to make it clearer, easier to read, and the role of `Poller.Task.withDeadline` would be clarified by making the raw constructor for that class `private`. The deadline should always be computed from the task `timeout`, should not be an arbitrary free variable.)

This code comes from [here (framework and trait)](https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-scala/blob/a905845ef08eb573a858024f1758d99e27c78e33/src/main/scala/com/mchange/sc/v2/concurrent/Poller.scala) and [here (implementation)](https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-scala/blob/a905845ef08eb573a858024f1758d99e27c78e33/src/main/scala/com/mchange/sc/v2/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorServicePoller.scala). (If you want to use it outright maven coordinates are [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/mchange-commons-scala).)